# Using RandomForestClassifier.decision_path, how do I tell which samples the classifier used to make a decision?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm using a `RandomForestClassifier` to classify samples with a binary outcome ("does not have the thing" vs "has the thing"). From the result of `RandomForestClassifier.decision_path`, how do I determine which samples contributed to the classification decision?

The [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.decision_path) says:

> ### Returns:
>
> #### indicator : sparse csr array, shape = [n_samples, n_nodes]
>
> Return a node indicator matrix where non zero elements indicates that the
>   samples goes through the nodes.
>
> #### n_nodes_ptr : array of size (n_estimators + 1, )
>
> The columns from indicator[n_nodes_ptr[i]:n_nodes_ptr[i+1]] gives the indicator value
>   for the i-th estimator.

Unfortunately, these terms are opaque to me. `indicator[x:y]` on a matrix of dimension `[n_samples, n_nodes]` seems like it is a mistake (shouldn't it be `indicator[sample, n_nodes_ptr[i]:n_nodes_ptr[i+1]]`?), but even then, I'm not sure what to do to take a "node indicator" and find what feature the node refers to. I can find examples using `decision_path` for `DecisionTreeClassifier`, but not for `RandomForestClassifier`.

Comment: I think you are right, it should be `indicator[sample, n_nodes_ptr[i]:n_nodes_ptr[i+1]]` . Though I did not get what you mean by the rest of your sentence ".. but even then, I'm not .... refers to".

Comment: @EmmetB, I’m asking how to interpret the decision path into samples that were inspected.

Comment: Can you point a one example for DecisionTreeClassifier?

Comment: @EmmetB, found it here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding the output of `RandomForestClassifier.decision_path` is easier when you realize that the `sklearn` conventions are to put as much stuff as possible inside `numpy` matrices.

`decision_path` returns the horizontal concatenation of every decision tree's `decision_path`, and the second return value informs you of the bounds of each sub-matrix. Using `decision_path` on a `RandomForestClassifier` is therefore equivalent to using `decision_path` on each of `RandomForestClassifier.estimators_`. For a one-row sample, you can walk the results like this:

```
indicators, index_by_tree = classifier.decision_path(data_row)
indices = zip(index_by_tree, index_by_tree[1:])
for tree_classifier, (begin, end) in zip(classifier.estimators_, indices):
    tree = tree_classifier.tree_
    node_indices = indicators[0, begin:end].indices
```

Instead of treating each node as a separate object, the tree instance has the following properties:

- `feature`
- `value`
- `children_left`
- `children_right`

Each are arrays or matrices documenting the features of tree nodes identified by their index. For instance, `tree.feature[3]` tells you which feature node 3 tests against; `tree.value` tells you about the tree's values as a 3D array, the first dimension being the node number and the last one containing the classification value and the threshold value. (I don't know what the second dimension is. It only has one element in my case.) `tree.children_left[5]` tells you the *node number* of node 5's left child, and as you guessed, `tree.children_right[6]` tells you the node number of node 6's right child.

In addition to *these* arrays, `DecisionTreeClassifier.decision_path` is also an array, where `decision_path[N]` is non-zero if node #N was visited in the decision process.

To walk back the features that were tested, you can do something like this:

```
for index in node_indices:
    feature = tree.feature[index]
    if feature >= 0:
        features.add(feature)  # where `features` is a set()
```

Note that this tells you about the features which were tested, nothing about their value or how they impacted the result.